# Importing S3 method from another package

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to import a S3 method, `predict` from another package `pls`. I have a function which uses these predicted values. The problem is, when compiling the package:

```
Error : object 'predict' is not exported by 'namespace:pls'
```

I've put together [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sebastian-c/5219249) as a minimal example which highlights my problem and contains the following R file:

```
#' Test function
#' 
#' @importFrom pls predict
#' 
#' @export

myfunc <- function(x){
  stopifnot(class(x) == "mvr")
  predict(x)*2
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To summarise this as the original (below) is now out-dated and in places erroneous or misleading.

The proximal issue is that there is no function named `predict` in the **pls** package; there are some unexported S3 methods for `predict` but no such `predict`. So you can't import this. The `predict` generic lives in the **stats** package and you'll need to import from there as discussed below.

Your package needs to have `Depends: pls` in the `DESCRIPTION` in order for the correct `predict` method to be available to R. There's nothing in **pls** that you can specifically import.

You also need to import the `predict` generic from the **stats** namespace, so add

```
#' @importFrom stats predict
```

as that will import the generic in you packages namespace. You will also want to add `Imports: stats` to your `DESCRIPTION` file to indicate that you need the **stats** package; previously we didn't have to declare dependencies on the set of base packages shipped with R (i.e. the non-Recommended ones that ship with R).

---

#### Original

The main issue here is the **pls** doesn't define  a function/method `predict`. It provides several methods for the `predict` generic, but not the generic itself.

You need to import the generic from the **stats** package, if you need it - I'm not sure you do as you aren't creating a function that needs or builds on the generic. At the minimum you'll need

```
#' @importFrom stats predict
```

though you may need/want to import the entire **stats** namespace - depends what your package does beyond the function your are currently working on.

The other issue is that `predict.mvr` is **not** exported from the **pls** namespace

```
> require(pls)
Loading required package: pls

Attaching package: ‘pls’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    loadings

> predict.mvr
Error: object 'predict.mvr' not found
> pls::predict.mvr
Error: 'predict.mvr' is not an exported object from 'namespace:pls'
> pls:::predict.mvr
function (object, newdata, ncomp = 1:object$ncomp, comps, type = c("response", 
    "scores"), na.action = na.pass, ...)
```

As such you can't just import it. Hence your package needs to have `Depends: pls` in the `DESCRIPTION` in order for the correct `predict` method to be found.

Comment: Or instead of putting `pls` in Description DEPENDS, just use `pls:::predict.mvr` directly (and make sure `pls` is at least in Description IMPORTS to guarantee its installation).

Comment: It's not good to use `pls:::predict.mvr` directly, triple-colons are a sign that you're poking around where the author didn't intend you to.

Comment: I have just solved a similar problem by putting the relevant package in Imports and adding importFrom("package", "method") in namespace.