# R S3 method not exported from namespace

Tags: r, namespaces, package, vegan

Why do I have this error message :

```
> vegan::reorder.hclust
Error: 'reorder.hclust' is not an exported object from 'namespace:vegan'
```

While this S3 method is well available. For example if I type `help(reorder.hclust, package = "vegan")` I obtain the intended help page and `vegan:::reorder.hclust` displays the source code of the function on the console...
Also the `NAMESPACE` file of my `vegan` installation contains `S3method(reorder, hclust)`.

I would like to use this function in another package were I need to import it or use `vegan::reorder.hclust`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_BE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_BE.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_BE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_BE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_BE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_BE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_BE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-49     compiler_3.4.3  Matrix_1.2-11   parallel_3.4.3  tools_3.4.3    
 [6] mgcv_1.8-23     yaml_2.1.18     nlme_3.1-131.1  grid_3.4.3      permute_0.9-4  
[11] vegan_2.4-6     cluster_2.0.6   lattice_0.20-35
```

Comment: This is basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563640/importing-s3-method-from-another-package

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't manage to find this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because `vegan` doesn't export that function.  It can give help for things that aren't exported.  Using three colons `vegan:::reorder.hclust` displays internal functions that are not exported; normally you should avoid using those.

However, when the `vegan` package is loaded, its `reorder.hclust` function will be added to the methods table for `reorder`.  So you just need to make sure that it is loaded, and then if `hc` is an `hclust` object, `reorder(hc)` will call the `reorder.hclust` method.  You can do this by putting `requireNamespace("vegan")` into your code, or importing something from `vegan` in your NAMESPACE file.

If there are two `reorder.hclust` methods (defined by different packages that are both loaded), then I don't think there's an easy way for you to specify the `vegan` one other than using `vegan:::reorder.hclust`, which CRAN will object to.  You would need to ask the `vegan` maintainer to export their function so you could access it using the legal `vegan::reorder.hclust`, or copy the code into your own package, or some other inconvenient approach.

Comment: `utils::getFromNamespace("reorder.hclust", "vegan")` is one approach to use the function and pass CRAN test.

Comment: The docs warn against using `getFromNamespace`:  "should not be used in production code".  So CRAN may add this to its tests later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Something I don't understand : isn't `S3method(reorder, hclust)` the way to export it from vegan (this is in the NAMESPACE file of the package) ?

Comment: To summarize : 3 solutions for the moment : 1) contact the vegan developer to ask him to export the function (but how if `S3method(reorder, hclust)` is not the way to do that ?), 2) copy the code in my package (not very nice - this is what I do for the moment) 3) according to the answer in the similar question pointed by @RolandASc : add `Depends: vegan` in the DESCRIPTION of my package to force this package to be attached (not very nice either). And maybe also ( use `utils::getFromNamespace("reorder.hclust", "vegan")` but this does not seem to be recommended.

Comment: **vegan** *exports* that function, but you did not use it appropriately. If you have a method function like `reorder.hclust`, you should use it as `reorder(<hclust.object>)`, but it won't work when used as `reorder.hclust(<any.object>)`. This also holds for any other **vegan** S3 method function: for instance, `plot.cca(<cca.result>)` will fail, but `plot(<cca.result>)` will work.

Comment: R has a fairly complicated model for scoping.  The `S3method` declaration in NAMESPACE *only* adds that method to the `reorder` method table, which is not the same as exporting it.  Code outside of `vegan` can't see the function unless it uses `:::` or `getFromNamespace`, or the code is the generic using that method table.

Comment: Thanks for your additional comments. @Jari Oksanen : I have been using this `reorder` methods for `hclust` objects as you recommend for years (by the way thanks for these very useful function you developed that should indeed be in base R...). Now that I want to embed my functions in a package I struggle to import the `reorder.hclust` method in my package... So I tried different possibilities. I don't see how I can import this function otherwise. I don't understand neither why the `S3method(reorder, hclust)` code you used in `NAMESPACE` seem to be not enough to let me import it.

Comment: Why not call it the way Jari and I have suggested, i.e. as `reorder(hc)`?

Comment: @user2554330 : It seems not possible to use `reorder(hc)` in my package unless I attach the whole `vegan` package either by an explicit call to `library(vegan)` within the code of my package (which is what I do in a local R script) or by adding `Depends: vegan` in the DESCRIPTION of my package. I read that attaching a whole external package seems to be not generally recommended in package development (eg because it modifies the search path of the user and increases the risk of conflicts).

Comment: What about the suggestions in my answer, `requireNamespace` or importing something from `vegan`?  By the way, you should also look at the `getS3method` function, which probably does what you want.

Comment: Adding `requireNamespace(vegan, quitely = TRUE)` in my package package function then `reorder(hcl_object)` indeed works ! It loads the package without attaching it (as `vegan::reorder` would do if it worked and if I understand well how all this works). I have tried Importing from`vegan` in my `NAMESPACE` file (eg `importFrom("vegan", "reorder.hclust")`) without success... `getS3method` works only if vegan is attached but not if it is only loaded ! Thanks again for your help and patience !

Comment: Just two followups:  the double dot notation *does not* cause the package to become attached, only loaded.  It only works on functions exported from the package.  So `vegan::vegdist` would trigger loading of the package if it is installed.  Similarly, `importFrom("vegan", "vegdist")` would work to get it loaded, but you can't import something like `reorder.hclust` because it was not exported.

Comment: I am preparing a new **vegan** release next week. I could export `reorder.hclust` if you have a serious need and think it is the best way to go. What kind of need do you have?