# self-written function does not work when it's started from package

Tags: r, function, r-package

I have written a function to automatically normalize my flow cytometry data using gaussNorm from the package flowstats. This function works just fine when I include it in my script. However, when I implement it in my package that I have prepared, It throws an error message saying 'cannot transform class flowSet into data frame'.

The code of my function looks like this:

```
flow_normalize2 <- function(df, id.channel, channels) {

  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  df <- df[,c(channels, id.channel)]
  if(!is.numeric(df[,id.channel])) {warning("Input dataframe must be purely numeric!")}


  ids <- df[,id.channel] %>% unique
  myflowdata <- lapply( ids, function(i) flowCore::flowFrame(as.matrix(df[df[,id.channel]==i,])) )

  fst <- flowCore::flowSet(myflowdata)
  transform.func <- logicleTransform()
  transform.list <- flowCore::transformList(channels, transform.func)
  fst <- transform(fst, transform.list)
  fst.norm <- flowStats::gaussNorm(fst, channel.names = channels, max.lms = 1)[[1]]
  fst.norm <- rbind(flowCore::fsApply(fst.norm, as.matrix, use.exprs = TRUE))
  fst.norm <- as.data.frame(fst.norm)

  id.verif <- paste0(id.channel,"norm")
  df[,channels] <- fst.norm[,channels]
  df[,id.verif] <- fst.norm[,id.channel]

  if(identical(df[,id.channel],df[,id.verif])) { print("gaussNorm normalization successful") }

  df[,id.verif] <- NULL

  return(df)

}
```

I have already tried to include the specifications of the package to use (i.e. flowCore and flowStats) but it still doesn't work when I try to start it from my package.
Can someone please help?

Comment: hard to answer, since your problem is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). However, this looks like some sort of missing functionalities (methods) from the flowCore package. Try `library(flowCore)` within the function -- and, if this works, try [importing flowcort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563640/importing-s3-method-from-another-package)

Comment: After you get the error, run `traceback()` and you should be able to see exactly which line causes the error.

Comment: I don't know anything about the packages you are using, but if the input `df` is a `flowSet` object, then `as.data.frame(df)` might not work without an `as.data.frame.flowSet` method loaded from one of the other packages.  If this is the case, you may need to track down that method so you can call it explicitly with `::`, or just add the whole package to your `Depends` so it is loaded when your package loads.

Comment: Side note, please save the RStudio tag for problems specific to the RStudio editor, like if you have code that runs on the command line but doesn't run in RStudio.

Comment: my input `df` is no flowSet but a dataframe. Also, I tried to include `library(flowCore)` inside the function as well, but it didnt work.

Comment: (1) if `df` is a `data.frame`, why do you need `df <- as.data.frame(df)`? (2) still not reproducible: please give examples for input objects `df`, `id.channel` and `channels` (eg. pick from one of the packages); (3) you could even give a **minimal** workable version of the package (ie. Description, R and Namespace file)

Comment: (1) I see that the conversion to data frame might seem redundant but I got some cases where the input was actually a tibble and since I don't like tibbles, I included this extra step to really make sure that the input my function is working with is indeed a dataframe. (2) yeah, I guess my description might be a bit scarce, sorry for that. For the input data, I assume a dataframe `df` with measuring variables stored in `channels`. Since these values should come from multiple test subjects (otherwise, normalization wouldn't be feasible), the `id.channel` columns annotates the ID of the subject

Comment: (3) sorry, what exactly do you mean? I don't understand that point.